# How can i render the json data in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I render JSON data in react component? Actually, I want to render every array to the different unordered list.

JSON Data

```
"value":{
        "h3":[
           "Best selling products",
           "Best Corporate Laptops",
           "BEST PRICED LAPTOPS",
           "Shop By Brands"
        ],
        "h4":[
           "Lenovo Thinkpad Touchscreen Yoga X380",
           "Lenovo thinkpad T440S",
           "Lenovo thinkpad T470"
        ],
        "h5":[
           "View All",
           "View All"
        ]
     }
```

What I tried

```
import { Disclosure } from '@headlessui/react'
const DisclosureHelper = ({data}) => {

  //console.log(data);
  let valuesArray = Object.values(data);
  valuesArray.map((values)=>{

    values.map((ind)=>{

      return <li>{ind}</li>

    });

  });
 }

 export default DisclosureHelper;
```

Comment: so you want to have multiple <ul> each having <li> with each array elements ?

Comment: yes! i wants to have each array in ul

Comment: I'm confused as of how you want it to be rendered? Do you want all the heading tags to be in a list? Can you edit your question to show an example output of the HTML?

Comment: There code is missing at least 2 `return` statements

Comment: What errors are you getting? Just looking at your code, since you are turning your object to an array, the value of your key would just be an array so in order to map through them properly, you would need to specify the correct index of the array you want to have rendered. You could instead use `let valuesArray = Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key])` then simply specify which array list you want rendered by doing something like `<li>{valuesArray[0]}</li>`. In short you would need to build out your menu/list

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan is it something are you looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-pike-nn5lhs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan Can you update your question with an expected output sample?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want something like the below.

You want to have a title/list name called
`h3`, then under `h3`, some list item that comes from the array of your key `h3` in your object something like the below.

```
 h3
 1. Best selling products
 2. Best selling products
 3. Best selling products
 4. Best selling products
```

When using `Object.values()` like you are in your code, you will be turning the values of your keys into arrays so for example (The example was taken straight out of the MDN docs):

```
    const object1 = {
      a: 'somestring',
      b: 42,
      c: false
    };

console.log(Object.values(object1));
// Expected output: Array ["somestring", 42, false]
```

So if you had the values of your keys as arrays, you would need to know which array index to map through. Another issue is the order of the key-value pairs will be lost since everything just gets turned into a an array
with no way for you to get the key without over complicating your code.

The answer provided below is using `Object.entries()`which basically
returns the key and its value in their own array. i.e `["h3",["1", "2"...]], ["h4", ["1", "2", "3"]]`
For example (The example was taken straight out of the MDN docs):

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// Expected output:
// "a: somestring"
// "b: 42"
```

The reason for using `Object.entries()` over `Object.values()` is simply because of code readability and ease of use (it somewhat preserves the order of the key-value pair). You only need to know the index of the key which will be `0` in this case and the very next index which is `1` is going to be it's value since each key-value pair is grouped into its own array.

**PLEASE SEE BELOW CODE SNIPPET FOR ANSWER**

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

// Turned the JSON data into an object for readability and testing sake.
  let value = {
    h3: [
      "Best selling products",
      "Best Corporate Laptops",
      "BEST PRICED LAPTOPS",
      "Shop By Brands"
    ],
    h4: [
      "Lenovo Thinkpad Touchscreen Yoga X380",
      "Lenovo thinkpad T440S",
      "Lenovo thinkpad T470"
    ],
    h5: [
      "View All",
      "View All"
    ]
  }


// We are using Object.entries() so that we can get the Key-Value Pair 
  in their own array.
  let valuesArray = Object.entries(value);
  
// Here we are mapping through the value and since each key-value pair 
 are in their
// own array, we can easily set the correct indexes in our JSX.
   const lists = valuesArray.map((list, index) => {
return (
  <div key={index}>
    <h3>{list[0]}</h3>
    <ul>
      {/* You can also further iterate through the list[1] arrays and 
       display
      displayed them in a more appealing manner. */}
      <li>
        {list[1].map((val) => {
          return <li>{val}</li>;
        })}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
 // Here we Simply Use Our list variable inside JSX and we have the desired result
      {lists}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct but i wants h2,h3,h4 to be rendered automatically!

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan Please see above for updated answer using your current code style